# How do I display a default source if the first one fails?

Tags: angular, image, string-interpolation

I got this case where I am trying to display a general image if the image doesn't exit on the server.

I want to make it using ternary operator, but the "src" doesn't apply to the second condition.

```html
<div class="test-picture">
   <img src="{{(test?.picture)? test.picture : '/images/test.png'}}" alt="test Image">
</div>
```

Comment: Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Angular, you should have a look at

```
<img [src]="myPath"/>
```

instead of `<img src="">`

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<div class="test-picture">
        <img [src]="(test.picture)? test.picture : 'assets/images/test.png'" alt="test Image">
    </div>
```

**Make sure you have your back up image is inside
 Assets directory of project or add it to assets in `angular.json`**.